# spring boot + cassandra lightweight transaction update

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

is there any way to implement update with lightweight transaction without writing query ? How can i implement example from casandra

```
UPDATE cycling.cyclist_name
SET firstname = ‘Roxane’
WHERE id = 4647f6d3-7bd2-4085-8d6c-1229351b5498
IF firstname = ‘Roxxane’;
```

by

```
CassandraOperations cops;
cops.update()
```

or

```
cops.batchOps()
```

InsertOptions works fine with

```
 InsertOptions
.builder()
.ifNotExists(true)
.build();
```

Comment: Spring Data for Apache Cassandra right now only supports `IF EXISTS`/`IF NOT EXISTS` conditions. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-575 for extending conditions to criteria queries.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.2 they have an api to specify condition check official [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/2.2.0.M4/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/UpdateOptions.UpdateOptionsBuilder.html)

```
public UpdateOptions.UpdateOptionsBuilder ifCondition(Filter condition)
Use light-weight transactions by applying IF condition. Replaces a previous ifCondition(Filter) and ifExists(boolean).
Parameters:
condition - the condition to apply for conditional updates, must not be null.
Returns:
this UpdateOptions.UpdateOptionsBuilder
Since:
2.2
```